# Schema Creation Failed: Not unique table/alias: 'tbl

Tags: php, sql, left-join

![Any help  with this error? which table name should I change the alias?][1]

```
                    SELECT
                            C1.answer1 AS answer1,
                            C2.answer2 AS answer2,
                            C3.answer3 AS answer3,
                            C4.answer4 AS answer4,
                            C5.answer5 AS answer5,
                            C6.answer6 AS answer6,
                            C7.answer7 AS answer7,
                            C8.answer8 AS answer8,
                            C9.answer9 AS answer9,
                            C10.answer10 AS answer10
                            FROM tblprelimanswer A
                            LEFT JOIN tblprelimstudentans a1
                            ON A.answer1 = a1.answer1
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer2 = a1.answer2
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer3 = a1.answer3
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer4 = a1.answer4
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer5 = a1.answer5
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer6 = a1.answer6
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer7 = a1.answer7
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer8 = a1.answer8
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer9 = a1.answer9
                            LEFT JOIN tbl
                            ON A.answer10 = a1.answer10
```

Is my table changing alias name were correct? Which are to be corrected?
Correct Me with my errors. Help me to get rid of this.Pls.. Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Are you trying to join your 2 tables based on all those fields?  In that case you  have a single LEFT JOIN with ON (a.foo=a1.foo AND a.foo2=a1.foo2 ...)

Comment: Yeah two tables..Thanks Joe :)

Answer (score 0):

You're joining to `tbl` multiple times without aliasing it. If you're joining to the same table multiple times, each time you need to give it a unique alias.

It could be that instead of additional `LEFT JOIN` you really just want additional criteria in your `ON`, in which case you can use `AND`:

```
LEFT JOIN tblprelimstudentans a1
       ON A.answer1 = a1.answer1
      AND A.answer2 = a1.answer2
      AND A.answer3 = a1.answer3
      AND A.answer4 = a1.answer4
      AND A.answer5 = a1.answer5
      AND A.answer6 = a1.answer6
      AND A.answer7 = a1.answer7
      AND A.answer8 = a1.answer8
      AND A.answer9 = a1.answer9
      AND A.answer10 = a1.answer10
```

I'm not sure what you're intending here, but it looks like you might be working with a bad design.  If you post sample data/schema and desired result people will be able to get to the root of the issue rather than just the syntax problem.

Comment: Yeah i think im working on a bad ones..answers were columned in two diff tables ..the values of tblanswer and tblcorrectanswer are to be compared..

Comment: BTW thank you for the help byanswering the question  :) Really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want your `from` clause to define the `C` aliases.  I would guess it would be something like this:

```
                        FROM tblprelimanswer A
                        LEFT JOIN tblprelimstudentans a1
                        ON A.answer1 = a1.answer1
                        LEFT JOIN tbl c1
                        ON c1.answer2 = a1.answer2
                        LEFT JOIN tbl c2
                        ON c2.answer3 = a1.answer3
                        LEFT JOIN tbl c3
                        . . .
```